# Access SQL query needed to trim down the result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access database and need to create a query to trim down the result. For example:

here is the table:

```
-------------------------------------
search code | relation | environment |
-------------------------------------
Server.PRD  | installs | Production  |
-------------------------------------
Server.DEV  | installs | Development |
-------------------------------------
```

The result that I need to display in a query view:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
search code short | search code | relation | environment |
---------------------------------------------------------
Server            | Server.PRD  | installs | Production  |
---------------------------------------------------------
Server            | Server.DEV  | installs | Development |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

It's difficult for me to design a query to display the result as above. Therefore I tried to break down the task into small pieces, but now I am stuck on the very first step:

I tried to cut off the 'PRD' or 'DEV' characters (**some of them are 4 characters like 'PROD' and they are not always at the end of a search code e.g. it could be 'Server.PROD.DB'**), the query I ran was:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'PRD' FROM SELECT search code FROM TABLENAME)
```

but this apparently doesn't work. Could someone please give me some ideas to write a query to display the result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `LEFT([search code], LEN([search code])-3)`

**EDIT**: To search for the `.`, use the `INSTR` function, like this: `LEFT([search code], INSTR([search code], '.') - 1)`

**EDIT**: To handle the NULL value, empty string, etc:

```
IIF
(
   (INSTR([search code], '.') = 0 OR [search code] IS NULL), 
   [search code], 
   LEFT([search code], INSTR([search code], '.') - 1)
)
```

Note this does not handle more than one `.` in the same value.

Comment: thanks for quick response.LEFT function works! but what I need is more than cutting off the last three characters of every search code. Please refer to the bold sentence in my question. sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [search code short] = LEFT([search code], InStr([search code], '.') - 1),
       [search code],
       relation
       environment
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: Your SELECT <column correlation name> = <expression> construct doesn't work for me in ANSI-92 Query Mode. Is it just an ANSI-89 Query Mode thing?

Comment: ...also doesn't handle all eventualities e.g. the NULL value, empty string, etc.

Comment: Try changing '[search code short] = LEFT([search code], InStr([search code], '.') - 1)' to 'LEFT([search code], InStr([search code], '.') - 1) AS [search code short]'.
The question says nothing about NULLs or empty strings ... [:)]